# Powershell: Listening for Telnet response text

Tags: powershell, match, telnet

This is one of those specific real-world problems that is probably very simple to do.  I'm just too rusty on my old BBS/terminal code to remember how at the moment.

I have a Powershell script that opens a Telnet session to a remote server, and then issues commands to that server based on a text file.  It also is designed to spit all the text coming back from the server into a log.

```
    ## Read output from a remote host
    function GetRemoteOutput
    {
      ## Create a buffer to receive the response
      $buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024
      $encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding

      $outputBuffer = ""
      $foundMore = $false

      ## Read all the data available from the stream, writing it to the
      ## output buffer when done.
      do
      {
        ## Allow data to buffer for a bit
        start-sleep -m 10000

        ## Read what data is available
        $foundmore = $false
        $stream.ReadTimeout = 12000

        do
        {
          try
          {
            $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)

            if($read -gt 0)
            {
              $foundmore = $true
              $outputBuffer += ($encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $read))
              write-host $outputbuffer
            }
          } catch { $foundMore = $false; $read = 0 }
        } while($read -gt 0)
      } while($foundmore)

      $outputBuffer
    }
```

The problem arises when I have to wait for the server at the other end of the Telnet session to indicate it is ready.  The above implementation simply uses Start-Sleep (ten seconds!), and then sends the next command 'blind'.

What I'd like to do is, start a buffer to grab what the session server is sending to my box, and then trigger the next command based on if I see a prompt coming back from the terminal session within that buffer.

Example (this is the prompt from an IBM DS400 San Controller, the target of the script)

xxxxxxSANCTRLnnn[A]>

Now, the name of these will change based on their location (xxxxxx), the actual SAN being accessed (nnn) and which of the two controller modules in the SAN (A or B) I'm accessing.  So a regex -match statement would work great for the actual 'pattern matching' of the system prompt. My question to the Scripting Guy is, what methods would work to:

1) get the script to pause while it buffers output from the terminal
2) pass that output to a log file
3) pattern-match on the expected "prompt" so as to then issue the next command

Thanks in advance!  :D

Comment: The regex that I'm looking to use for the prompt matching is:


`$promptmatch = "^\w{6}SANCTRL\d{3}\[[A,B]\]\>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about do...until?

do {start-sleep -sec 1; (and refresh the read from the server)} until (!$foundMore)

Comment: That may be a possibility. I'll investigate it! Thank you.